# Is there any way to get current legitimate user list from Twitter in 5000 to 10000

Tags: python, twitter

I am doing some research of spam detection on Twitter where my program is dynamic enough which can built a tree of datastructure of metadata of user and his tweets just taking a parameter as Screen_name or Twitter id but collecting legitimate user name and spammer name is a manual task. (If there is any other  way please suggest me.)

Comment: What are the criteria you're collecting those users from.

Comment: They should be legitimate user which has different motive in twitter than spammer like (posting malicious link, phishing, dissimination of pornograpich content, Introducing noise in Twitter, by wrong use of Twitter feature mention, hashtag, short url )

Comment: That would be pretty challenging based on the way you approach it, you'll need to use the streaming API to get just users where you can filter based off language and location if needed. Then from there obtain the tweets of those users and possibly use NLTK to find out what they're tweeting about and classify them accordingly. That's just a suggestion not a solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use of **Stream API** could help you. You can collect the real time information there and using some clustering algorithms and data mining techniques can solve it.

Comment: I agree with your point , Then i will not have rate limitation also, but i commented above , i need only legitimate users

Comment: You must determine some strategy which gonna return you some sort of list which is close to optimal set of legitimate users. For generating such strategy one of the ways to build and determine some kind of algorithms which is close to pattern recognition, data mining, and etc. One of the best and most obvious ways is using Streaming API.  Good Luck. Sorry for late responce